# RichTextBox control is only using first formatting

Tags: c#, .net, richtextbox, rtf, richtext

I am using Visual Studio 10, .NET Framework 4 and was creating a Rich Text Box Control for Text Input. I am formatting text ONLY by writing the

```
*RichTextBox*.SelectionFont = new Font(currentFontFamily, currentFontSize, currentFontStyle);
```

Method.

When I am now accessing the Rtf formatted String via the *RichTextBox*.Rtf property, it works, but ONLY contains the first formatting.

For example:

**Hello** *World*

results in:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1031{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Verdana;}}
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\cf1\b\f0\fs18 Hello World\par
}
```

which actually is **Hello World**

This is the same for everything. Fonts, Sizes, Colors, Formatting and so on. Can anyone help??

Comment: Show some sample code of where one your buttons applies formatting to your RTB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is propably because the properties SelectionStart and SelectionLength are not valid. If you explicit limit the selection via those properties the RTF-output will be as expected:

```
richTextBox1.Text = "Hello World";

// limit selection
richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 5;

richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Tahoma", 12, FontStyle.Bold);

MessageBox.Show(richTextBox1.Rtf);
```

becomes

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1031\b\f0\fs24 Hello\b0\f1\fs17  World\par
}
```

**Edit:**

As the asker mentioned below the real cause of the problem was a call to TrimEnd():

```
richTextBox1.Text.TrimEnd()
```

As soon as he removed it everything worked as expected.

Comment: Hello Soner, thank you for the quick response. When I am changing the Font programatically, as you suggest, it works. However I am changing it via a control, so that while typing, you see what you get. When specifically marking text (e.g. mouse) and formatting (via the button), SelectionStart and SelectionLength are correct, but the export is still not correct. I think I am missing something else here...

Comment: No problem. What do you mean by "changing it via a control"? Is your app offering a wordpad like toolbar? Can you narrow down the problem to a few lines of code and post it here?

Comment: yes, its a word pad kind of tool bar. I created a new project with this simple application and as you might have expected: It works there! I will investigate the differences to my actual project. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem.

```
*RichTextBox*.Text = *RichTextBox*.Text.TrimEnd();
```

causes the Rtf to lose some of its formatting. I thought it would have only had an influence on the text itself, not the formatting (especially when just removing whitespace characters) - I guess I was wrong.

Thanks again *viertausend* for the help